# Challenges that may occur while automating Single Page Application Testing using WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, single-page-application

What sort of challenge will occur while automating Single Page Application tests using WebDriver

Comment: please be clear what do you mean by challenges

Comment: What kind of issues I may face if i automate SPA application with WebDriver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi answer to your question can very person to person but i think you should take care of following things :

1.for personal front please do not use POM page object model framework for SPA use data driven or even keyword driven both will work fine.

2.use small re-usable methods so that u can skip code redundancy.Also it will help in overcoming various exception like stale element exception.

3.also try to divide your SPA in various blocks (for example header ,footer,grid etc -hence when you will do any operation you know where you have to go it will give you a clear idea and easy code maintenance)

for now i can think of these points hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks Rajnish for your valuable response.  I came to know that while automating SPA, synchronization issue (because of async element calls) is the most common and I need to handle this very frequently. Is there any other similar issues that may occur.  Any specific reason for suggesting not to use POM for SPA?

Comment: yes that it is what i mentioned in step 2 yeah POM is most suitable for those application where you have more pages also POM itself means Page Object i.e every page is an object ,if you will apply then there is only on page so form logic of POM there will be only one object with all methods and it will become very tough to identify which code is where

Comment: hmm usually SPAs use views  so even thought you have one URL you could potentially divide your POM in terms of views e.g once you click a button on one view A it returns view B in your model etc.